# In videojs, I can add a Text Track event handler, but I can't remove it

Tags: javascript, typescript, html5-video, video.js

I added a handler for the 'cuechange' event to a Text Track" This works fine. But I can not find a way to remove this handler. I tried each of instructions below to remove the handler, but it still gets called.

```
onHiliteSpeech() {
  const textTrack = this.videojsComponent.getTextTrack();

  const handleCueChange = () => {
   ...
   console.log(in event handler);
   }
  };

  if (this.bevents) {
    textTrack.addEventListener('cuechange', handleCueChange);
  } else {

    // none of the below instructions remove the handler.
    textTrack.removeEventListener('cuechange', handleCueChange);
    // textTrack.removeAllListeners();
    // textTrack.removeAllListeners('cuechange');
    // textTrack.eventListeners = null;
  }
}
```

In my videojsComponent:

```
getTextTrack(): TextTrack {
  return this.player.textTracks()[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I found the problem. The function "handleCueChange" should not be a nested function within onHiliteSpeech.

I moved handleCueChange outside of onHiliteSpeech. (This also involved some work to allow handleCueChange to access some OnHiliteSpeech properties.) The new working code became:

```
const handleCueChange = () => {
   ...
   console.log(in event handler);
   }
};

onHiliteSpeech() {

  textTrack.addEventListener('cuechange', this.handleCueChange);
  ...
  textTrack.removeEventListener('cuechange', this.handleCueChange);
}
```